# MongoDB : Getting all the content of an object nested in an array using aggregation/projection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nested

I'm having an issue returning an object that is inside of a nested array `myShows.showChoices` using projection/aggregation. (if that is even the correct way of approaching this).

Whenever I would try to use .find() by looking for the name or Id of the show, it would simply return the name or Id without any other content. I'm trying to return all the contents of the object. Including the name, overview, poster_path, ect... (Essentially the object itself)

My Schema:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
email:{
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    required: 'Please Provide an email address'
},
name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please supply a name',
    trim: true,
},
myShows: {
    topRated: [],
    showChoices: []
});
```

An object I would $push into `myShows.showChoices` would look something like

```
{
 name: "Name of Show",
 poster_path:"/x2WKIbiwhLoWgLFbT2I0Gwq8U1J.jpg",
 genre_ids: [37, 878],
 overview: "show description",
 id: 63247
}
```

I have tried:

```
const show = await User.find(
    { _id: req.user.id },
    { showChoices: { $elemMatch: { name: "Name of Show" } }   }
)
```

**UPDATE: 1**

And several variations of projection/aggregation. This is my latest attempt. (Stuck on what to do after the last $match.)

```
const show = await User.aggregate([
            { "$match": {
              "_id" :  req.user._id,
              "myShows.showChoices.id": showIDVar
            }},
            { $unwind: "$myShows.showChoices" },
            { $match: {
                "myShows.showChoices.id": showIDVar
            }},
        ])
```

I think the issue with my past .find() queries were that I was searching only for the name or id of the show (not the _id)

```
const show = await User.find(
        { _id: req.user.id },
        { "myShows.showChoices": { name: "Name of Show" }   }
    )
```

Which would only return the name of the show itself. Is there anyway to return all the contents of the object by just querying the name?

Any advice on how to approach this?

```
        // Expected output is to have 
const show =
        {
         name: "Name of Show",
         poster_path:"/x2WKIbiwhLoWgLFbT2I0Gwq8U1J.jpg",
         genre_ids: [37, 878],
         overview: "show description",
         id: 63247
        };
```

Comment: I cant understand your question; can you tell us what your expected output is?

Comment: I edited the post to show the expected output, and to try and be a bit clearer. I'm not sure if aggregation/projection is the right way to go with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there; just need to add `$project` stage:

```
const show = await User.aggregate([
            { "$match": {
              "_id" :  req.user._id,
              "myShows.showChoices.id": showIDVar
            }},
            { $unwind: "$myShows.showChoices" },
            { $match: {
                "myShows.showChoices.id": showIDVar
            }},
            { $project: {
                "myShows.showChoices.name": 1,
                "myShows.showChoices.poster_path": 1,
                "myShows.showChoices.genre_ids": 1,
                "myShows.showChoices.overview":1


            }},
        ])
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish.